# Is there a TSLint/ESLint rule to prevent (boolean === true) type of comparisons?

Tags: eslint, tslint

Is there a TSLint/ESLint rule to prevent unnecessary boolean comparison like:

```
if (result === false) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in rule or a custom rule that does this. However, sounds like a reasonable feature request!

Comment: I've submitted a rule request to core eslint: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TSLint supports rule `no-boolean-literal-compare` which does just this.

`"no-boolean-literal-compare": true` in the `rules` array will enable this feature.

Documentation link: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-boolean-literal-compare/

Answer (score 2):

You can currently accomplish this with ESLint:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
     {
        "selector": "BinaryExpression[operator=/^(==|===|!=|!==)$/][left.raw=/^(true|false)$/], BinaryExpression[operator=/^(==|===|!=|!==)$/][right.raw=/^(true|false)$/]",
        "message": "Don't compare for equality against boolean literals"
     }
]
```

The selector disallows usage of `==`, `===`, `!=`, and `!==` when either (or both) of the operands are boolean literals.

---

[Source](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9743#issuecomment-353418510)